# How to retrieve the updated cell value in a Material UI Datagrid using GridCellParams

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I want to get the newly modified value in a cell, but when using the GridCellParams interface, the 'value' property only gives me the previous value of the cell I was previously modifying. This is working asynchronously, which is not beneficial to me. The use of processRowUpdate is also not suitable in my case, since it returns the entire row when I only need to access the cell that has been modified.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { DataGrid, GridCellParams, GridColDef, GridRowsProp } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const columns: GridColDef[] = [

  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70, editable: true },
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First Name', width: 150, editable: true },
  { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last Name', width: 150, editable: true },
  { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', type: 'number', width: 90, editable: true },

];

const rows: GridRowsProp = [

  { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 },
  { id: 2, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 22 },
  { id: 3, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', age: 30 },

];

const MyDataGrid: React.FC = () => {

  const handleKeyDown = (params: GridCellParams, event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {

    if (event.key === 'Enter') {

      //This print the last value, not the new one
      console.log('Enter key pressed on row:', params.row, ' value: ', params.value);

    }

  };

  return (

    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        onCellKeyDown={(params, event) => handleKeyDown(params, event as   React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>)}
      />
    </div>

  );
`your text`
};

export default MyDataGrid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the updated cell value in `params` before the cell is updated, which is why it doesn't work. Meaning, the callbacks, such as `onCellKeyDown` & `onCellEditStop` are called before the the cell is updated by the DataGrid internally (as also suggested by the names of the callbacks itself).

You'll have to use `processRowUpdate` only to get the access to the updated value, and since you're looking to get only the value that was updated, you can check the [diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff#diff) using the new row value and the old value like this -

```
import * as React from "react";

import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowsProp } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import { diff } from "deep-object-diff";

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70, editable: true },
  { field: "firstName", headerName: "First Name", width: 150, editable: true },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last Name", width: 150, editable: true },
  { field: "age", headerName: "Age", type: "number", width: 90, editable: true }
];

const rows: GridRowsProp = [
  { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 25 },
  { id: 2, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", age: 22 },
  { id: 3, firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith", age: 30 }
];

const MyDataGrid: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        editMode={"cell"}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        processRowUpdate={(newVal, oldVal) => {
          const result = diff(oldVal, newVal);
          console.log(result);
          // Do something with result
          return newVal;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyDataGrid;
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-brown-ht9frl?file=/Demo.tsx)